# Reverse recovery behavior for stuck non circular robots

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have a robot that is having issues getting stuck. In a lot of situations, a simple reverse operation would un stick it. Rotate recovery doesn't work well because my robot's turning center is offset from its body. Before I get to writing one from scratch, is there any reversing type recovery behavior i could get move_base to use?

[image: image description]

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271482/reverse-recovery-behavior-for-stuck-non-circular-robots/) by [psammut](https://answers.ros.org/users/31213/psammut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 258 on 2017-09-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could check out stepback_and_steerturn_recovery:
http://wiki.ros.org/stepback_and_steerturn_recovery

---

Originally posted by [ce_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/28528/ce_guy/) with karma: 77 on 2018-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1